# Jquery control event handler execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two handlers in separeted files. I want to test in the second handler if the first has already executed. For example :

If file one :

```
$("#input1").on("focusout", function(){
    alert("Hi");        
});
```

If file two

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function(){
    if(input1 focusout handler is not running) {
        alert("clicking");
    }
});
```

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: You should explain your issue instead! "test in the second handler if the first has already executed" is not the same thing than: "input1 focusout handler is not running"

Comment: I can already tell you that 'input1 focusout handler is not running'. In Javascript, event handlers are executed *sequentially*, except if you invoke one from the code of another, but that's not your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can offer to do it in two ways:

1. Global variables

   ```
   // Somewhere in JS code
   focus_handler = false;

   $("#input1").on("focusout", function(){
       focus_handler = true
       alert("Hi");
       // some code
       focus_handler = false
   }


   $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
       if(!focus_handler) { // or focus_handler === false
           alert("clicking");
       }
   });
   ```
2. JQuery data

   ```
   $("#input1").on("focusout", function(){
       $("#btn1").data('focus_handler', true);
       alert("Hi");
       // Some handler
       $("#btn1").data('focus_handler', false);
   }

   $("#btn1").on("click", function(){
       if(typeof($(this).data('focus_handler')) != 'undefined') {
           alert("clicking");
       }
   });
   ```